# SQL/AJAX results appearing locally but not on website

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, cpanel

I've been doing a project where I've used HTML, Javascript, PHP and MySQL to create a simple CRUD application. I used XAMPP on my local server and it worked fine. On my website I have replicated the database in cPanel using MySQL wizard, phpmyadmin and updated my config.php document accordingly. I know that this works because when I go to the individual PHP files through the URL of my website, with error reports on, I can see no errors and the correct response
I am using the exact same structure as what I have locally, and have also hard refreshed the cache, but I still can not see the results.

A simplified example of a response I am missing is:
HTML:

```
<ul id="results"></ul>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(
    showResults()
);

function showResults() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "libs/php/department/getAll.php",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(result){
            const numberOfDepartments = result['data'].length;
            for(let i=0; i < numberOfDepartments; i++) {
                $('#results').append('<li>result['data'][i]['id']</li>');
            }               
        }           
    })
}
```

PHP

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$executionStartTime = microtime(true);

include("../config.php");

header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');

$conn = new mysqli($cd_host, $cd_user, $cd_password, $cd_dbname, $cd_port, $cd_socket);

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    
    $output['status']['code'] = "300";
    $output['status']['name'] = "failure";
    $output['status']['description'] = "database unavailable";
    $output['status']['returnedIn'] = (microtime(true) - $executionStartTime) / 1000 . " ms";
    $output['data'] = [];

    mysqli_close($conn);

    echo json_encode($output);

    exit;

}   

$query = 'SELECT * FROM department';

$result = $conn->query($query);

if (!$result) {

    $output['status']['code'] = "400";
    $output['status']['name'] = "executed";
    $output['status']['description'] = "query failed";  
    $output['data'] = [];

    mysqli_close($conn);

    echo json_encode($output); 

    exit;

}

$data = [];

class Department{
    public $id;

    public function setId($id){
        $this->id = $id;
    }
    public function getId(){
        return $this->id;
    }
}

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $dept = new Department();
    $dept->setId($row['id']);
}

$output['status']['code'] = "200";
$output['status']['name'] = "ok";
$output['status']['description'] = "success";
$output['status']['returnedIn'] = (microtime(true) - $executionStartTime) / 1000 . " ms";
$output['data'] = $data;

mysqli_close($conn);

echo json_encode($output);
```

?>

Is there anything wrong with my code that I should change for uploading on my website, or are there any debugging techniques I can use to find out why it is not displaying the results?

Comment: Open the developer tools with f12 in your browser and refresh page. You will see the request of the ajax request sent in the network section. You can examine the error from there.

Comment: `append('<li>result['data'][i]['id']</li>');` you have nested single quotes with no escaping which will be causing an error